# Is it possible to use EFI to create fully cross-platform disk driver?

Tags: driver, efi, uefi

I need to create a driver, which will behave similar to software RAID. E.g. driver will need to communicate to multiple physical disks (or maybe even network resources), and shall look like a disk to the OS.

So two main questions are:

1) Are EFI drivers recognized and supported by Windows, MacOS X and Linux? E.g. can these systems use EFI disk drivers, and ?

2) Is it possible in theory to write such a driver for EFI? My primary concern is possibility of accessing other EFI disk drivers from your own virtual disk driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only have time for a quick-ish reply, forgive me for brevity!

### Are EFI drivers recognized and supported by Windows, MacOS X and Linux? E.g. can these systems use EFI disk drivers, and ?

To my knowledge, only the bootloaders for these OSs use the UEFI driver stack for loading the native OS kernel and drivers. Once [ExitBootServices()](http://wiki.phoenix.com/wiki/index.php/EFI_BOOT_SERVICES#ExitBootServices.28.29) is called by the bootloader, most of the drivers are unloaded, and (according to the spec) no calls to handle-based drivers may happen after this, meaning no disk drivers. Like a traditional bootloader, a UEFI bootloader is only using the basic drivers long enough to load the OS's native drivers. You can also use these drivers in the preboot environment if you'd like (although it sounds like you don't!).
**TL;DR** No, these systems can't use UEFI drivers other than for loading the OS.

### Is it possible in theory to write such a driver for EFI?

You should definitely be able to layer your UEFI driver on top of the existing stack. It might be a little tricky if you haven't worked with UEFI before, but conceptually the system is very modular. There appear to be a number of resources on the Internet to [help](http://feishare.com/attachments/105_202%20UEFI-Drivers.pdf) [you](http://uefi.blogspot.com/2012/03/uefi-driver-writers-guide-wizard.html) [out](http://kurtqiao.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-write-uefi-driver.html), and there is always *Beyond BIOS: Developing with the Unified Extensible Firmware Interface* by Vincent Zimmer.
As far as testing goes, you can use one of the simulators provided in [Intel's EDKII](http://sourceforge.net/projects/edk2/) (if you're on Windows, you should probably use the Nt32 project, it works well with Visual Studio).
**TL;DR** Yes, you can write this driver, but it will only work for bootloaders and applications in the pre-boot environment.

Comment: Really hit the nail on the head. I would like to add with windows for example. After acpi.sys is loaded it uses windows drivers which are very similar to uefi drivers but one thing needs to be considered. Uefi drivers are just there to boot the system up not to run all the time (like in early windows). After that performance written drivers which conform to windows are loaded. Yes hardware vendors have to write 2 drivers. One to interface Uefi and one to interface windows.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Are EFI drivers recognized and supported by Windows, MacOS X and Linux? E.g. can these systems use EFI disk drivers, and ?

No. Once you run ExitBootServices() it goes bubye. You can have a RunTimeDXE Driver, but those are incredibly limited. They cannot allocate memory (the VM Map is controlled by the OS) and they don't have access to any EFI APIs any more. They can be used to transfer information from the Firmware to the OS, but a better choice would be a private EFI Table.

> 2) Is it possible in theory to write such a driver for EFI? My primary concern is possibility of accessing other EFI disk drivers from your own virtual disk driver.

The bootloader is the only one able to use the EFI drivers. If you want to go to the OS level, you need to write your own OS driver that gets the information from the EFI driver using EFI System Tables. Such examples are Full Disk Encryption implementations.

In theory you would need to write an EFI Block Driver based, a Windows IO Filter or BUS/Volume Driver, an OS X IOStorageFamily KEXT and a Linux Block Device Driver all of them transferring the information from firmware to OS using EFI Tables, Variables or RuntimeDXE.

RuntimeDXE implementations are incredibly difficult due to the conversion to Virtual Memory Maps from the flat addressing available in the EFI.